# Populate a HTML placeholder with a Custom Label

Tags: apex, visualforce, html, customlabel

I'm building a Pre-form Chat on a Visualforce page, but the problem is, the website gonna be multilingual, so now i need to put a Custom Label as a placeholder, but I'm using html instead of apex style, something like this:

```
<input style="float: left; margin-right: 15px; margin-bottom:10px; width: 170px;" type="text" name="liveagent.prechat:ContactFirstName" id="firstName" placeholder="Nome" required="true" />
```

I tried to replace with my Label like `{$Label.LA_ola}`, but no luck

I tried changing the `<input>` to `<apex:inputField>` and using the `html-placeholder` but again, no luck.

Any ideas to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used {$Label.LA_ola} change it to

```
{!$Label.LA_ola}

placeholder="{!$Label.LA_ola}"
```

you are missing ! in your syntax

Comment: Rao, u R a life-saver man, i own u a coffee.